# Increasing a number based on a decimal less than 100?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, decimal, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm currently working on some SUMIF formulae which will calculate certain values against specific conditions. All of the values to be calculated are decimalised but are based on 0.80 = 1.00.

As an example if I have 1.25 and 1.60 to add together I would want the outcome to read 3.05 but currently, I would get an outcome of 2.85.

Is it possible to amend the highest number a decimal can read before it converts to 1?

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(QUOTIENT(D1:D3, 1))+
          QUOTIENT(SUM(MOD(D1:D3, 1)), 0.8)+
               MOD(SUM(MOD(D1:D3, 1)), 0.8))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That works perfectly thanks. Now I just need a bit of help with making this work alongside the SUMIF formula I mentioned earlier. My database is transport related with regards to vehicles and mileage accumulated - I have a 'haulage' tab which has column A for vehicle number & column B for mileage. I then have a 'Vehicle' tab which lists all of the vehicles in column A and has a total mileage for each vehicle in column B which I've used the following formula to calculate from the Haulage tab - =SUMIF(Haulage!A2:A100,A9,Haulage!B2:B100). This column B is where I require the decimal 0.80 to work

Comment: try to replace D1:D3 from answer with your sumif formula

Comment: Unfortunately I'm struggling to make it work with my SUMIF formula instead of your original D1:D3 answer. I've tried multiple variations of fitting it in and either get ERROR or N/A as a response in the cell

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I'm on my phone and wouldn't know how to I'm afraid

Comment: I've made some slight progress by using the following formula: =ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(QUOTIENT(SUMIF(Haulage!A2:A100,A9,Haulage!B2:B100), 1))+ QUOTIENT(SUM(MOD(Haulage!B2:B100, 1)), 0.8)+ MOD(SUM(MOD(Haulage!B2:B100, 1)), 0.8)) - Would you say this looks right as it's still not working correctly? Seems to be adding up all of the decimals in Haulage!B2:B100 and adding them onto the actual value in all rows in my Master sheet

Comment: I've not been able to get your filter to work - is it a case of me copying your filter formula as you've put it or does it still require my SUMIF formula? Also, I've tweaked my formula that got me close last night to - =ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(QUOTIENT(SUMIF(Haulage!A2:A100,A9,Haulage!B2:B100), 1))+ QUOTIENT(SUM(MOD(SUMIF(Haulage!A2:A100,A9,Haulage!B2:B100), 1)), 0.8)+ MOD(SUM(MOD(SUMIF(Haulage!A2:A100,A9,Haulage!B2:B100), 1)), 0.8)) - this has stopped the issue I was having yesterday regarding all of the decimals being added together and included in every cell but now the 0.8 decimal isn't working?

Comment: did you try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(QUOTIENT(FILTER(Haulage!B2:B100, Haulage!A2:A100=A9), 1))+
          QUOTIENT(SUM(MOD(FILTER(Haulage!B2:B100, Haulage!A2:A100=A9), 1)), 0.8)+
               MOD(SUM(MOD(FILTER(Haulage!B2:B100, Haulage!A2:A100=A9), 1)), 0.8))` ?

Comment: This looks to have worked under initial testing. Will scrutinise it deeper over the weekend but fingers crossed your persistence has paid off! Just out of curiosity, if I wanted to move the Haulage tab into its own spreadsheet, would we still be able to make this formula work so I input into one spreadsheet and the outcome is calculated in another?

Comment: its possible. you just need to use IMPORTRANGE to import values from one spreadsheet into different spreadsheet

Comment: That's good news. Can IMPORTRANGE be added to the formula you have come up with for me?

Comment: first you need to run single importrange fx to connect your sheets and authorize access. then you can use: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(QUOTIENT(FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("ID","Haulage!B2:B100"), IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Haulage!A2:A100")=A9), 1))+ QUOTIENT(SUM(MOD(FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("ID","Haulage!B2:B100"), IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Haulage!A2:A100")=A9), 1)), 0.8)+ MOD(SUM(MOD(FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("ID","Haulage!B2:B100"), IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Haulage!A2:A100")=A9), 1)), 0.8))` (replace the ID with actual spreadsheet id)

Comment: I have now sorted the IMPORTRANGE for my spreadsheet but you'll be pleased to know I have stumbled across another issue. The column I've added the IMPORTRANGE to is a mileage column which I'd like to read either a value (as per my manual input to the Haulage spreadsheet) or 0 if no entries are made. However, where no entries are made for a particular number I'm getting a '#N/A' response because 'no matches are found in FILTER evaluation'. This is also impacting my totalling of this column as not all values are numeric so is also turning out a N/A in the total cell. Can you help with this pls?

Comment: wrap all your importranges into iferror like:  `IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE(...),0)`

Comment: Struggling to get the IFERROR to work. I've tried multiple variations along with use of IFNA instead of IFERROR. This is my last attempt: =ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(QUOTIENT(FILTER(IFNA(IMPORTRANGE("ID","Haulage!$I$3:$I$2000"),0), IFNA(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Haulage!$B$3:$B$2000"),0)=I10), 1))+ QUOTIENT(SUM(MOD(FILTER(IFNA(IMPORTRANGE("ID","Haulage!$I$3:$I$2000"),0), IFNA(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Haulage!$B$3:$B$2000"),0)=A13), 1)), 0.8)+ MOD(SUM(MOD(FILTER(IFNA(IMPORTRANGE("ID","Haulage!$I$3:$I$2000"),0), IFNA(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Haulage!$B$3:$B$2000"),0)=A13), 1)), 0.8)) - can you see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I've changed the link to my spreadsheet to read "ID" as it wouldn't fit into the comment box otherwise :)