# Increasing a number based on a decimal below 100 (part 2)

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Back in November I posted this question in this post - [Increasing a number based on a decimal less than 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58799625/increasing-a-number-based-on-a-decimal-less-than-100)

@player0 kindly assisted me to come up with the following formula that works absolutely perfectly:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(QUOTIENT(IFERROR(FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AGMJxw5D5TNFI19dvpPCT0Jl6QNu5rRX1bcLqHYJ0-w/edit?usp=drivesdk","Haulage!$I$3:$I$30000"), IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AGMJxw5D5TNFI19dvpPCT0Jl6QNu5rRX1bcLqHYJ0-w/edit?usp=drivesdk", "Haulage!$B$3:$B$30000")=A15), 0), 1))+ QUOTIENT(SUM(MOD(IFERROR(FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AGMJxw5D5TNFI19dvpPCT0Jl6QNu5rRX1bcLqHYJ0-w/edit?usp=drivesdk","Haulage!$I$3:$I$30000"), IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AGMJxw5D5TNFI19dvpPCT0Jl6QNu5rRX1bcLqHYJ0-w/edit?usp=drivesdk", "Haulage!$B$3:$B$30000")=A15), 0), 1)), 0.8)+ MOD(SUM(MOD(IFERROR(FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AGMJxw5D5TNFI19dvpPCT0Jl6QNu5rRX1bcLqHYJ0-w/edit?usp=drivesdk","Haulage!$I$3:$I$30000"), IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AGMJxw5D5TNFI19dvpPCT0Jl6QNu5rRX1bcLqHYJ0-w/edit?usp=drivesdk", "Haulage!$B$3:$B$30000")=A15), 0), 1)), 0.8))
```

This obviously fetches data from another spreadsheet into the one I was using the formula in but I am now considering moving the 'Haulage' worksheet from the spreadsheet I am using importrange from and into the same spreadsheet as the one where the above formula is going.

Before I proceed with this, I just wanted to check on how simple a process that would be in terms of amending the above formula to remove the need for the importrange whilst maintaining the same outcome. Would it just be a case of removing the importrange and spreadsheet key from the formula and then removing any unnecessary brackets or would I be looking at a brand new formula?

Comment: It is the first case, just replace `IMPORTRANGE` constructions with the ranges themselves. Better try it.

Comment: Wouldn't this formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(QUOTIENT(FILTER(Haulage!B2:B100, Haulage!A2:A100=A9), 1))+ QUOTIENT(SUM(MOD(FILTER(Haulage!B2:B100, Haulage!A2:A100=A9), 1)), 0.8)+ MOD(SUM(MOD(FILTER(Haulage!B2:B100, Haulage!A2:A100=A9), 1)), 0.8))`, provided by @player0 in a comment on the referenced post, do the trick?

Comment: Indeed, that did work @lamblichus - should have read through the full discussion I had with player0 at the time as I remember there being a lot of back and forth.

Comment: @The_Train Good to know your issue was solved. Also, questions should have answers. Would you consider posting an answer explaining how this problem got solved?

Answer (score 2):

Amending my original formula to this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(QUOTIENT(FILTER(Haulage!B2:B100, Haulage!A2:A100=A9), 1))+ QUOTIENT(SUM(MOD(FILTER(Haulage!B2:B100, Haulage!A2:A100=A9), 1)), 0.8)+ MOD(SUM(MOD(FILTER(Haulage!B2:B100, Haulage!A2:A100=A9), 1)), 0.8))
```

solved the issue I was having. Thanks to @lamblichus for their assistance on this